# I have used a GB of data in less than 24 hours, how is this possible

Tags: settings

I got my android phone a week ago. This morning I recieved an text from telus telling me I have used 75% of my data, then an hour later I recieved a text saying I used 95%. Since I was sleeping and was not using my phone I want to know if this is at all possible, I took my phone into telus and all the settings for wifi are off. Is someone taking internet from me? What should my settings be?

Comment: Wi-Fi is not the same as mobile data.  I believe we have some questions on tracking what uses your mobile data, try a search and see if they help.

Comment: You actually want to switch wifi on if you're having these problems. If you have a home/office/school/etc internet connection that has wireless access, then while you're connected to that any data will go through the wifi, not the mobile phone company's network, so it won't count toward your data limit.

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of background processes and applications will use cell data bandwidth.  If you've installed some new apps recently, which given your phone is only a week old seems likely, check to see if some of them are doing anything in the background.

If you list your apps, perhaps we could shed some light on which ones might be data hogs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading any games? Some of the more complex games could weigh hundreds of megabytes, and they download additional resource data when they're first run.

Comment: Duplicates my comment above...

Answer (score 0):

My Verizon data widget was telling me numbers I couldn't believe.  I went through a gigabyte over night and was at 3 gigabytes for the month most in the last 10 day of the cycle.

I found the [My Data Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5tb2JpZGlhLmFuZHJvaWQubWRtIl0.) app in the market and that told me which app was causing the problem. The app breaks down data by Wireless and Wifi and shows you how much data each app used. I LOVE this app.